# Android application getting crashed while opening one activity to another

Tags: java, android

I am developing android application, In my app I would like to open UHFMainActivity by clicking on layout in UHFMenuActivity but application is getting crashed. It works absolutely fine when I use another activity instead of UHFMenuActivity.I think there is a problem in UHFMenuActivity.
Here is my UHFMenuActivity code...

```
    public class UHFMenuActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout layoutAdd, layoutScan, layoutReport, layoutList;
    ImageView imageScan;
    Button btnNext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar);

        layoutAdd = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutAdd);
        layoutScan = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutScan);
        layoutReport = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutReport);
        layoutList = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutList);
        imageScan = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageScan);

        layoutAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(UHFMenuActivity.this, AddStudentActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        layoutScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(UHFMenuActivity.this, UHFMainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        layoutReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(UHFMenuActivity.this, ViewReportActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        layoutList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(UHFMenuActivity.this, ListStudentActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

activity_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="110dp">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:text="Student Attendance"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:textSize="30sp" />

   </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/layoutAdd">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:src="@drawable/add" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/layoutScan">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageScan"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:src="@drawable/scan" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/layoutReport">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:src="@drawable/report" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/layoutList">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:src="@drawable/list1" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.uhf"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" 
        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="11"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />                 
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo_thsti_trans"
            android:label="AsseTrack"
            android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">

            <activity
                android:name="com.example.uhf.activity.UHFMenuActivity"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity android:name=".activity.UHFMainActivity"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Here is my log errors.

```
06-15 11:26:36.831 4308-4328/com.example.uhf E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                   Process: com.example.uhf, PID: 4308
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load DeviceAPI from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.uhf-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.uhf-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
                                                                       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
                                                                       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
                                                                       at com.rscja.deviceapi.DeviceAPI.<clinit>(DeviceAPI.java:1459)
                                                                       at com.rscja.deviceapi.RFIDWithUHF.getDeviceAPI(RFIDWithUHF.java:41)
                                                                       at com.rscja.deviceapi.RFIDWithUHF.init(RFIDWithUHF.java:214)
                                                                       at com.example.uhf.activity.BaseTabFragmentActivity$InitTask.doInBackground(BaseTabFragmentActivity.java:179)
                                                                       at com.example.uhf.activity.BaseTabFragmentActivity$InitTask.doInBackground(BaseTabFragmentActivity.java:173)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
    06-15 11:26:37.458 4308-4340/com.example.uhf E/ContentValues: Couldn't get json from server.
    06-15 11:26:37.494 4308-4340/com.example.uhf E/ContentValues: Couldn't get json from server.
    06-15 11:26:37.534 656-689/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '42467078 com.example.uhf/com.example.uhf.activity.UHFMainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
    06-15 11:26:37.534 656-689/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '4247b2d8 com.example.uhf/com.example.uhf.activity.UHFMainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: Post the log please

Comment: post the error which you are getting..

Comment: edit your question and also post UHFMenuActivity.this, UHFMainActivity.class code

Comment: logcat please share and show `UHFMainActivity.class`

Comment: The error is within the Asynctask that you have somewhere in `UHFMainActivity.class`

Comment: do you using AsyncTask in UHFMainActivity.class or UHFMenuActivity.class ?

Comment: in UHFMainActivity.class

Comment: @SatyendraSharma so please post your UHFMainActivity.class code, its very helpful

Comment: Bingo!!! Now it's working, the problem was on AsyncTask in UHFMainActivity.class Thanks a lot for your support...